# I have 3 different programs login,home and main which I have connected using subprocess module .. now after converting to exe, this transition fails

Tags: python, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Basically, I gave login.py as main source file in auto-py-to-exe and the other 2 files as additional files. Now that I have converted them into an exe file, only login works. Whenever I try to transit to other 2 files, a window opens and closes in split second...

I am really not sure of what could be the problem.. there were no errors and problem when I just had those 3 programs... but am facing it after converting them to a single exe file